# Text based survival Game

Tags: java

So I just whipped up this quick little demo game in like 30 minutes and I was wondering 2 things:

- How could I organize my code more?
- Would you be willing to play a game like this?

I know that I could use classes but I'm a bit inexperienced them. I'm confused on how to get variables from specific classes. Would I need to import them into the main method class?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class mainGame
{
  public static Scanner kboard = new Scanner(System.in);
  public static boolean loop = true;
  public static int treesInArea = 0;
  public static int day = 0;
  public static int wood = 0;
  public static int woodCollected = 0;
  public static int woodLevel = 0;

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    System.out.println("__________________________________");
    System.out.println("   Welcome to seul...Lets begin   ");
    System.out.println("   You woke up in the middle of   ");
    System.out.println("  a forest. Use the command walk  ");
    System.out.println(" in order to walk into a new area ");
    System.out.println("__________________________________\n");

    while(loop == true)
    {
      String choice = kboard.nextLine();

      if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("walk"))
      {
        treesInArea = (int)(Math.random() * 20);
        System.out.println("__________________________________");
        System.out.println("The number of trees in this area is");
        System.out.println(treesInArea + " trees");
        System.out.println("__________________________________\n");
        day++;
        System.out.println("          It is day " + day + "    ");
        System.out.println("__________________________________\n");
        System.out.println("  Current usuable commands are :   ");
        System.out.println("  - Chop tree\n");
      } else
        if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("choptree") || choice.equalsIgnoreCase("chop tree"))
      {
        if(treesInArea < 1)
        {
          System.out.println("There are no trees in this area.");
        } else
        {
          woodCollected = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
          treesInArea --;
          wood += woodCollected; 
          woodLevel += (int)(Math.random() * 2);

          System.out.println("__________________________________");
          System.out.println("      You collected " + woodCollected + " wood");
          System.out.println("      Your total wood = " + wood);
          System.out.println(" Your total woodcutting level = " + woodLevel);
          System.out.println("__________________________________\n");
        }
      }

    }

  }
}
```

Comment: One question at a time, please.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Also read an follow [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

Comment: This question is almost like, "How do I code?".  You'll need to narrow it down.  One thing to note, you are using global fields for no reason.  You can privatize those fields since you are only using them in this class. You might want to research [Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-138747.html) in general.

Comment: Im taking an ap computer sci course in highschool right now and using classes is very confusing to me...sorry for the broad question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could improve your code in 4 main ways:

---

1 • Your code-indentation is not great, it should be a 4 space(or just press tab) indent after class name, loops, if statements etc. Example:

```
private methodName() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++;) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

---

2 • It is easier to read your code when braces are right after methods/loops, and it takes less space, such as(5 lines of neat code):

```
 if (condition = true) {
     //do something
 } else {
     //do something else
 }
```

Rather than(7 lines of messy code):

```
 if (condition = true) 
 {
     //do something
 } else 
 {
     //do something else
 }
```

because when you have long `if-else` blocks, or long loops, it can become hard to read.

---

3 • You do not need to add spaces after a line, this does nothing. So this:

```
System.out.println("          It is day " + day + "    ");
```

Can become this:

```
System.out.println("          It is day " + day);
```

---

4 • Lastly, the best way to organize code is by "dividing and conquering". This means make [methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) even if they're very short, to prevent repeat-code and save time. For example, you printed this line: `System.out.println("__________________________________");` **7 times** in your program. If you make a method like the one below, you can save time and space, by avoiding repeat-code, and simply call the method using `printDivider();` wherever you used this line:

```
private static void printDivider() {
    System.out.println("__________________________________");
}
```

---

Yes, I would play your game(in fact i *did* play your game), but you could improve it, by adding more possibilities, or different 'paths' to go down, ending in different results.

Comment: Yes this is a very old post. Ive made a lot of improvements since then. If you want to check out the more finished game you can check out my youtube channel.https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC2_XXa5MO7NLmiQ6EJU6ivQ they are devlogs with download links...the next update should have a lot more stuff.

Comment: I like this answer however I do not prefer to use put the brackets right next to the statements just because it makes the code look all mushed together. Just my opinion but otherwise good answer. I was also looking for more of how to use classes but I figured that one out. So thanks a lot.